# How to configure postfix to reject emails which are pretended to be send from myhostname?

Tags: postfix, smtp

Suppose the Postfix mail service is serving domain `@mycompany.com`. Local network is 192.168.10.0/24. The attacker from Internet sends an email pretending it originates from `@mycompany.com`:

```
Received: from mycompany.com (unknown [37.139.129.8])
    by mycompany.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 967DB396B598
    for <admin@mycompany.com>; Mon, 14 Aug 2023 19:36:39 +0200 (CEST)
From: mailer-daemon@mycompany.com
To: admin@mycompany.com
```

Is there any option to reject email that has `From: *@mycompany.com` and does not originate from `mynetworks` (192.168.10.0/24)? I would think about adding

```
/^From: .*@mycompany\.com/ REJECT Invalid sender address
```

to `/etc/postfix/header_checks` but that will block all such emails irrespective the source IP while the intention is to allow clients from `mynetworks`.

Any further ideas or suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The need for doing this suggests you are not implementing the existing email spoofing controls that would protect your domain from abuse globally, and that you are using the same `smtpd` instance for inbound & outbound mail.

The proper solution for this would include:

1. Deploying DKIM & SPF.
2. Deploying a DMARC policy with `p=reject`.
3. Configuring OpenDMARC on the host for rejecting inbound, forged mail.
4. Using a separate `smtpd` instance as a *submissions* (`smtps`) for outbound mail.

If you started from the #4, you could already use the [`header_checks`](https://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html) as you suggest, but that would became unnecessary after you are finished with #1, #2 & #3.

---

Protecting the *envelope sender* from spoofing would be possible by allowing mail from trusted IP addresses and then rejecting the sender domain for the rest.

A solution with `hash:` (Berkeley DB) [table type](https://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html#types):

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    . . .
    permit_mynetworks,
    check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/access/sender_access,
    permit
```

And in the `/etc/postfix/access/sender_access`:

```
example.com  550 YOU ARE NOT ME.
```

This requires running `postmap /etc/postfix/access/sender_access` after modifications!

---

Another solution requires the [Postfix PCRE Support](https://www.postfix.org/PCRE_README.html), but is more flexible, as it enables, e.g., blacklisting entire TLDs.

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    . . .
    permit_mynetworks,
    check_sender_access pcre:/etc/postfix/access/sender_access,
    permit
```

And in the `/etc/postfix/access/sender_access`:

```
/example\.com$/  550 YOU ARE NOT ME.
/\.loan$/        550 .loan? no thanks, we have money.
```

Comment: Thanks. I have checked that solution also works with standard BDB map `check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/access/sender_access` with more simple content `mycompany.com  550 ...` – why do you suggest PRCE?

Comment: And I believe one can't use `$myhostname` variable in map file (supposed to be substituted)...

Comment: I've added both variants.